# how do I fix "/app/scripts/[foo].coffee is using deprecated documentation syntax" in hubot?

Tags: hubot

checking the heroku logs for my bot is showing messages like:

/app/scripts/tigger.coffee is using deprecated documentation syntax

but I can't seem to find what the undeprecated documentation syntax should be ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's normally due to the [TomDoc](http://tomdoc.org/) at the top of the files. There's a good example for a correct one [here](https://github.com/jjasghar/hubot-chef/blob/master/src/chef.coffee)