# Hubot Error: Script is using deprecated documentation syntax

Tags: hubot, rocket.chat

I am using docker compose to deploy Hubot. Everything works just fine for me after i ran "docker compose up". Hubot is online and works. 
However, I want to add my own scripts to it. I just got an error:

```
test.coffee is using deprecated documentation syntax.
```

This is exactly the same as [this issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22104525/how-do-i-fix-app-scripts-foo-coffee-is-using-deprecated-documentation-syntax)
But i can not get the point of the solution.

For more detailed screenshots please have a look at this [link](https://github.com/RocketChat/hubot-rocketchat/issues/292)

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the "*Documenting Scripts*" section of ["Hubot scripting documentation"](https://hubot.github.com/docs/scripting/)

The current format as of 2018-10-10 is:

```
# Description:
#   <description of the scripts functionality>
#
# Dependencies:
#   "<module name>": "<module version>"
#
# Configuration:
#   LIST_OF_ENV_VARS_TO_SET
#
# Commands:
#   hubot <trigger> - <what the respond trigger does>
#   <trigger> - <what the hear trigger does>
#
# Notes:
#   <optional notes required for the script>
#
# Author:
#   <github username of the original script author>
```

Include the header at the top of your script.  If it does not follow the above format, hubot reports a deprecation warning.

On my hubot, using this format seems to work.